# Rewriting GET request on sub-sub directory in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to rewrite a simple php GET request in a sub-subdirectory:

> `http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/?username=jakepunton`

To look a little something like this:

> `http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/jakepunton/`

#### Attempt

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?u/(.*?)/?$ u/index.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ u/index\.php\?username=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /u/%1? [L,R=301]
```

I've taken a look [here](https://www.taniarascia.com/rewrite-query-string-to-path-with-htaccess/) and I have no clue what I'm looking at.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Emma, thank you. That tool is awesome. Ideally I would like it to be more dynamic though as there will be other usernames on the platform too. How could I make it more fluid for multiple GET requests? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `test/o/u/` is a real directory, you may use these rules in `test/o/u/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/o/u/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?username=([^\&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?username=([^\&]+)&(edit)[=\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1/%2? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(edit)/?$ index.php?username=$1&$2=true [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. How would I then do another request from the same index.php file. For example http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/jakepunton/?edit=true to http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/jakepunton/edit/. Thank you in advance! Great help.

Comment: No, just a /test/o/u/ directory. On the index.php page I will be making 2 get requests, one for username and one for edit.

Comment: I don't understand. The internal URL is `http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/index.php`. On this page I'm making 2 get requests, individually. So the first one will be the username and then the second will be edit. I want the URL to look like this `http://localhost:8888/test/o/u/jakepunton/edit/`. The 'jakepunton' in the URL is from the username get request, and the edit is from the edit get request. Does this make sense?

Comment: It can only equal `edit` or `true` both do the same thing. It doesn't matter. Just as long as `?edit` is set.

Comment: My man! If I could +1 more than once I would. Thank you so much.